# Set default 100% zoom for iOS safari site rendering

Tags: html, mobile-safari

My web page is slightly larger then the iPad resoltion, so when I open it in iPad Safari window, it is horizontally scrollable. When I pinch out the view, the web site looks perfect. Can I, via setting some tags like `viewport` or some other, get the page to be fully displayed as soon as it loads?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this way:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Answer (score 9):

This stops the user from being able to re-scale the page as well, you can toggle this by changing user-scalable to 1 or limiting the amount of scalability by changing maximum-scale

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
```

Comment: You did, although you didn't include the user scalability and maximum scale.

Comment: No but it was relevant to the question, and may be useful for other people who search for a similar term.. What's the problem with offering additional information?